# numpy slice an array without copying it

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

I have a large data in matrix `x` and I need to analyze some some submatrices.

I am using the following code to select the submatrix:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.random.normal(0,1,(20,2))
>>> x
array([[-1.03266826,  0.04646684],
       [ 0.05898304,  0.31834926],
       [-0.1916809 , -0.97929025],
       [-0.48837085, -0.62295003],
       [-0.50731017,  0.50305894],
       [ 0.06457385, -0.10670002],
       [-0.72573604,  1.10026385],
       [-0.90893845,  0.99827162],
       [ 0.20714399, -0.56965615],
       [ 0.8041371 ,  0.21910274],
       [-0.65882317,  0.2657183 ],
       [-1.1214074 , -0.39886425],
       [ 0.0784783 , -0.21630006],
       [-0.91802557, -0.20178683],
       [ 0.88268539, -0.66470235],
       [-0.03652459,  1.49798484],
       [ 1.76329838, -0.26554555],
       [-0.97546845, -2.41823586],
       [ 0.32335103, -1.35091711],
       [-0.12981597,  0.27591674]])
>>> index = x[:,1] > 0
>>> index
array([ True,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False,
        True,  True, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False,
       False,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> x1 = x[index, :] #x1 is a copy of the submatrix
>>> x1
array([[-1.03266826,  0.04646684],
       [ 0.05898304,  0.31834926],
       [-0.50731017,  0.50305894],
       [-0.72573604,  1.10026385],
       [-0.90893845,  0.99827162],
       [ 0.8041371 ,  0.21910274],
       [-0.65882317,  0.2657183 ],
       [-0.03652459,  1.49798484],
       [-0.12981597,  0.27591674]])
>>> x1[0,0] = 1000
>>> x1
array([[  1.00000000e+03,   4.64668400e-02],
       [  5.89830401e-02,   3.18349259e-01],
       [ -5.07310170e-01,   5.03058935e-01],
       [ -7.25736045e-01,   1.10026385e+00],
       [ -9.08938455e-01,   9.98271624e-01],
       [  8.04137104e-01,   2.19102741e-01],
       [ -6.58823174e-01,   2.65718300e-01],
       [ -3.65245877e-02,   1.49798484e+00],
       [ -1.29815968e-01,   2.75916735e-01]])
>>> x
array([[-1.03266826,  0.04646684],
       [ 0.05898304,  0.31834926],
       [-0.1916809 , -0.97929025],
       [-0.48837085, -0.62295003],
       [-0.50731017,  0.50305894],
       [ 0.06457385, -0.10670002],
       [-0.72573604,  1.10026385],
       [-0.90893845,  0.99827162],
       [ 0.20714399, -0.56965615],
       [ 0.8041371 ,  0.21910274],
       [-0.65882317,  0.2657183 ],
       [-1.1214074 , -0.39886425],
       [ 0.0784783 , -0.21630006],
       [-0.91802557, -0.20178683],
       [ 0.88268539, -0.66470235],
       [-0.03652459,  1.49798484],
       [ 1.76329838, -0.26554555],
       [-0.97546845, -2.41823586],
       [ 0.32335103, -1.35091711],
       [-0.12981597,  0.27591674]])
>>>
```

but I would like x1 to be only a pointer or something like this. Copy the data every time that I need a submatrix is too expensive for me. 
How can I do that?

EDIT:
Apparently there is not any solution with the  numpy array. Are the pandas data frame better from this point of view?

Comment: You would `x1` to be a [*view*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/glossary.html#term-view) of `x`, but this is not possible with [*advanced indexing*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing). The numpy manual is pretty clear about that in the [section about indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing).

Comment: In a comment you state that you are recursively passing the data to a function. Why not leave the data alone in a global and pass the index on the stack?

Comment: I think that this will still require an advanced indexing that is equivalent to copy the data.

Comment: My impression is that this problem can be solved storing the data in a pandas dataframe but I am not sure about that and in each case I do not know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information for your array `x` is summarized in the `.__array_interface__` property

```
In [433]: x.__array_interface__
Out[433]: 
{'descr': [('', '<f8')],
 'strides': None,
 'data': (171396104, False),
 'typestr': '<f8',
 'version': 3,
 'shape': (20, 2)}
```

It has the array `shape`, `strides` (default here), and pointer to the data buffer.  A `view` can point to the same data buffer (possibly further along), and have its own `shape` and `strides`.

But indexing with your boolean can't be summarized in those few numbers.  Either it has to carry the `index` array all the way through, or copy selected items from the `x` data buffer.  `numpy` chooses to copy.  You have choice of when to apply the `index`, now or further down the calling stack.

Answer (score 4):

Since `index` is an array of type `bool`, you are doing advanced indexing.  And the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)  say: „Advanced indexing always returns a copy of the data.“

This makes a lot of sense. Compared to normal indexing where you only need to know the start, stop and step, advanced indexing can use any value from the original array without such a simple rule. This would mean having lots of extra meta information where referenced indices point to that might use more memory than a copy.

Comment: what if I use  `index = np.argwhere(x[:,1]>0).ravel()` ? This is not boolean any more

Comment: it will still be advanced indexing, unfortunately

Comment: `ndarray`'s data structure is ideal for fast linear algebra operations on them. This means that you need a constant stride from one element to the next (and this is possible with basic slicing). With advanced indexing you have a non constant stride from one element to the next one.

Answer (score 1):

If you can manage with a traditional slice such as

```
x1 = x[3:8]
```

Then it will be just a pointer.

Have you looked at using masked arrays? You might be able to do exactly what you want.

```
x = np.array([0.12, 0.23],
             [1.23, 3.32],
               ...
             [0.75, 1.23]])

data = np.array([[False, False],
                 [True, True],
                ...
                 [True, True]])

x1 = np.ma.array(x, mask=data)
## x1 can be worked on and only includes elements of x where data==False
```

Comment: I am recursively passing submatrix of the data to  a function that does not modify it. This is why I would like to pass only a view or something like this.

Comment: The point is that `x[index, :]` *is* a copy. Even if you do not store a reference to it, it is already eating up your memory.

Comment: yes, and I suspect masking will use a bit of copying and maintenance of indexes etc.