# subselect large numpy array without a copy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to select a subset of elements  from a large numpy array.

I'm near my memory limit so don't wish to create another array, rather I would like to do this downsampling in-place.

I've tried doing:

```
big_array = big_array[subset_of_big_array_indices]
```

But this results in an out of memory error.

Is there any way to do a selection (or deletion operation) in place?

Comment: afaik NumPy doesn’t copy. What happens if you use a different name for the slice than for the original array?

Comment: @mkrieger1 another out of memory error

Comment: Okay I was partly wrong, it does copy, depending on what kind of indexing is used. You'd have to show what exactly `subset_...` is. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30238092/numpy-slice-an-array-without-copying-it

Comment: Indexing with slices (`basic indexing`) produces a `view`.  Advanced indexing (e.g. with a list of indices) produces a copy.  Your operation has to make the copy before freeing up the old memory (that's assuming there aren't other views of the same base).